Prevent VSCode from deleting highlighted region with backspace
I'm using Awesome Emacs Keybindings in VSCode. One feature in Emacs is being able to set delete-active-region to nil so that backspace won't kill the highlighted region and only deletes the character at point.
Is there a way to configure this in VSCode?
